# How to fix a background-image getting "cut" in a post-back event on every create a new tab method called?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, background-image

Here are the .css and .aspx file "on-run" code. The script tag would come from the c# code on click event of a button which is inside the gridview to invoke the method which will create a new tab

--css file

```
.loginpage
{

    background: url('../Images/bg_login.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

--rendered aspx page

```
<script>
window.open('profile_m.aspx', 'MsgWindow');
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="loginpage">
<head><title>
    Admin
</title>

<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
    <form method="post" action="admin.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTM5MDIzODQwMw9kFgICAw9kFgYCAQ8PFgIeBFRleHQFBWFkbWluZGQCGg88KwARAwAPFgQeC18hRGF0YUJvdW5kZx4LXyFJdGVtQ291bnQCAmQBEBYAFgAWAAwUKwAAFgJmD2QWCAIBD2QWDmYPDxYCHwAFATJkZAIBDw8WAh8ABRRnZXJhbGRndWlvQHlhaG9vLmNvbWRkAgIPDxYCHwAFB2dlcmFsZDNkZAIDDw8WAh8ABQZsYWd1aW9kZAIEDw8WAh8ABQxhcnQgcGVyc29uYXNkZAIFDw8WAh8ABQVNb2RlbGRkAgcPDxYCHwAFBHRydWVkZAICD2QWDmYPDxYCHwAFATRkZAIBDw8WAh8ABRJnZ2xhZ3oyMkBnbWFpbC5jb21kZAICDw8WAh8ABQZnZXJhbGRkZAIDDw8WAh8ABQZsYWd1aW9kZAIEDw8WAh8ABQxhcnQgcGVyc29uYXNkZAIFDw8WAh8ABQVNb2RlbGRkAgcPDxYCHwAFBHRydWVkZAIDDw8WAh4HVmlzaWJsZWhkZAIEDw8WAh8DaGRkAhwPPCsAEQMADxYCHwNoZAEQFgAWABYADBQrAABkGAIFCWd2c1NlYXJjaA9nZAUJZ3ZyZXN1bHRzDzwrAAwBCAIBZJKBFx6jEOFQ4Xru0bjp5i5eDGFwsC9LzGAALrYnKk9G" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>


<!--- NAV --->
        <div id="header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a>Welcome <span id="lblUsername">admin</span></a></li>
                <li><a id="linkLogout" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;linkLogout&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Logout</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
          </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
        <!--- END NAV --->

        <!--- LOGO --->
        <div class="wide" style="margin-top: 100px">
            <div class="col-xs-5 line"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 logo text-center"><img src="Images/aptisthub.png" /></div>
            <div class="col-xs-5 line"></div>
        </div>
        <!--- END LOGO --->
        </div>

            <div class="container col-md-12 col-md-offset-0 col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0" id="content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                        <div class="panel panel-black">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">Admin Account</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                          <input type="submit" name="btnregister" value="Agency/Company List" id="btnregister" tabindex="2" class="btn btn-default" />
                                    </div>
                                   >Deactivated TALENTS will be unsearchable (non-caster accounts only)
                                    <!--- BUTTONS --->
                                    <div class="span12 text-center">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-pills center-pills">
                                            <li><input type="submit" name="btnmodels" value="models" id="btnmodels" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:161px;" /></li>
                                            <li><input type="submit" name="btnphoto" value="photographers" id="btnphoto" class="btn btn-primary" /></li>
                                            <li><input type="submit" name="btnma" value="make-up artists" id="btnma" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:161px;" /></li>
                                            <li><input type="submit" name="btnhs" value="hair stylist" id="btnhs" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:161px;" /></li>
                                            <li><input type="submit" name="btndes" value="designers" id="btndes" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:161px;" /></li>
                                            <li><input type="submit" name="btnfs" value="fashion stylist" id="btnfs" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:161px;" /></li>
                                            <li><input type="submit" name="btncaster" value="casters" id="btncaster" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:161px;" /></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--- END BUTTONS --->

                                    <!--- SEARCH BAR --->
                                    <div class="row margin-top-10">
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <div class="input-group">

                                                <input name="txtsearch" type="text" id="txtsearch" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by first name/last name and/or company/agency" />

                                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                    <input type="submit" name="btnsearch" value="search" id="btnsearch" class="btn btn-default" />
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--- END SEARCH BAR --->

                                    <!--- GRIDVIEW --->
                                    <div class="form-group margin-top-10">
                                        <div>
    <table class="table table-bordred table-striped" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="gvresults" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <th class="hide" align="center" valign="middle" scope="col">ID</th><th scope="col">Username</th><th scope="col">First Name</th><th scope="col">Last Name</th><th scope="col">Company / Agency</th><th scope="col">Profession</th><th align="center" valign="middle" scope="col">View Profile</th><th align="center" valign="middle" scope="col">Active</th><th align="center" valign="middle" scope="col">Deactivate</th><th align="center" valign="middle" scope="col">Activate</th>
        </tr><tr>
            <td class="hide">2</td><td align="center" valign="middle">geraldguio@yahoo.com</td><td>gerald3</td><td>laguio</td><td align="center" valign="middle">art personas</td><td>Model</td><td align="center" valign="middle"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;gvresults&#39;,&#39;viewprofile$0&#39;)">View</a></td><td align="center" valign="middle">true</td><td align="center" valign="middle"><input type="button" value="deactivate" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;gvresults&#39;,&#39;removal$0&#39;)" /></td><td align="center" valign="middle"><input type="button" value="activate" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;gvresults&#39;,&#39;activate$0&#39;)" /></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td class="hide">4</td><td align="center" valign="middle">gglagz22@gmail.com</td><td>gerald</td><td>laguio</td><td align="center" valign="middle">art personas</td><td>Model</td><td align="center" valign="middle"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;gvresults&#39;,&#39;viewprofile$1&#39;)">View</a></td><td align="center" valign="middle">true</td><td align="center" valign="middle"><input type="button" value="deactivate" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;gvresults&#39;,&#39;removal$1&#39;)" /></td><td align="center" valign="middle"><input type="button" value="activate" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;gvresults&#39;,&#39;activate$1&#39;)" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--- END GRIDVIEW --->

                                    <!--- GRIDVIEW --->
                                    <div class="form-group margin-top-10">

                                    </div>
                                    <!--- END GRIDVIEW --->

                                </fieldset>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br /><br /><br />
            </div>

        <!--- FOOTER --->
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" id="footer-body">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" >
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="howitworks.aspx" target="_blank">How it works</a></li>
                        <li><a href="terms.aspx" target="_blank">Term and Conditions</a></li>
                        <li><a href="policy.aspx" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a></li>

                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                        <li class="pull-right"><a><span id="Label5" style="font-size:smaller !important;">copyright © 2014 aptisthub.com. All Rights Reserved</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--- END FOOTER --->


<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="67467B03" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEdABJsTP4BDj4yQ0aBRRq+ENbcw/Y49wPR6Zh5eO9LorO2SdCTgulUm3dYnilRAOBrl/e0xrzHmBkch+q9CKebWdL/iOzTEfx0+38pU91rmhoD9PQYjyospQQtGGjbJbf6cGL+fdwiAMgw0oqjWFBhEOKTorzho+x2aYtOhE9/+uJaH5JxAIRrgi/qVgER/NontkskWJ/JCTvVyJq7dMsKVwpy5ZdTeOjJ4oGOO2ewXvk8iIyMbrZiIuRkJWoG/sQQsxSiaqltkb5QBKyivx79L91z188YFPbf3P5eAx0HS2iruOgrrACLRvOVyfkgpRzI9qfgu7hETH7S0uFQcOxaPfUZLz95eF/vzQANlld1j/iNeeewmfY45gcDciB+ljQ8Oqi67Sqw1IlwWw7cDnlddOFEsG41Vtx1qTGf4vrS2Giq0w==" />
</div></form>
        </div>

<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Chrome","requestId":"e3dbf7fdd23f4781a0d9b3438bbdf703"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:49690/7415574f4c5848d1b12e740079acd404/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

here is the visual representation:

on_load event and normal post-backs
the background image is fixed and normal

```
_____________
|    I       |
|    M       |
|    A       |
|    G       |
|____E_______|
```

but when my create a new tab method is called,
the page becomes cut as presented below.

```
_____________
|    I       |
|    M       |
|            |
|            |
|____E_______|
```

Comment: What is the question you are trying to ask?

Comment: How to maintain the background-image after a post back event coming from a new tab method called? Because for some reason the image keeps getting cut in the middle after the post back and when the new tab is created.

Comment: It almost seems like you have some sort of panel or <div> that is hidden overtop of the background judging by your small pictures... are you sure that on that new tab that there isn't anything covering that part of the background. while running the code in your browser hit f12, click on the magnifying glass in the top left corner and hover over the area that's cut off and see what is there